# Modify a row with CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm using CakePHP to show a frontend GUI for a MySQL database table. I've used [bake](http://www.codeforest.net/cakephp-from-scratch-baking-our-application) to auto generate the screens and I currently have a fully functioning app with View, Edit and Delete buttons per row. I want to add a button per row, called `Accept`, which should set `IsAccepted = 1` on the SQL row.

I've managed to add an `Accept` button per row as follows:

```
 echo $this->Html->link(__('Accept'), array('action' => 'accept', $product['Product']['ID']))
```

But the code in `ProductController.php` does not work:

```
 public function accept($id = null){
     ...
     $this->Product->IsAccepted = 1; // does not work, silently fails
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly edit a row using a per-row button?

Comment: This is not how any current or previous CakePHP version works. Check [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org), and please always mention your exact CakePHP Version!

Comment: also, the action you're calling is "approve", why is the function called "accept" ?

Comment: Typo! Sorry! My current CakePHP version is 2.4.4.

Comment: @ndm - The button is visible per row with the code I showed above! I simply copied the system used for View and Edit (they all have the same line of code, 1 line per button)... I just can't figure out the code in the controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cornelb I found the answer! This is the final code I used to modify a row, with a per-row button.

- Modifies the row when the per-row button is pressed (works just like a POST/AJAX button)
- A flash message that says "Accepted!" shows if saving succeeds
- Redirects back to the listing page (appears to never leave the listing)

This is the code that goes in `ProductController.php` (or whatever controller class you have):

```
public function accept($id = null) {
    if ($this->Product->exists($id)) {

        // save the row
        // you absolutely need to fill the 'id' slot, even if its not your primary key!!
        // this ensures that the row is EDITED, and not INSERTED!
        if($this->Product->save(array('id' => $id, 'ID' => $id, 'IsApproved' => 1, 'ApprovedDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())))){

                // show a "flash" message
                // (not Adobe Flash, just a message that shows on top of the list)
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product has been accepted!'));

                // this action does not have a view so no need to render
                $this->autoRender = false;

                // redirect to index view
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function accept($id = null){
     $this->Product->save(array('id' => $id, 'is_accepted' => 1));
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but this code executes an "INSERT" for some reason... and then crashes with `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`!

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array - "Creating or updating is controlled by the model’s id field. If $Model->id is set, the record with this primary key is updated. Otherwise a new record is create". Please try the options described in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming cake 2.1+
public function accept($id = null){
    if($this->Product->exists($id)) {
        $this->Product->saveField('is_accepted', 1);
        // success.. 
    }

    // else throw not found exception... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Try this.....**
<?php
public function accept($id = null) {
    $this->autoRender = false; // if action has not view.
    if ($this->Product->exists($id)) {

        $this->Product->id = $id;
        if ($this->Product->save(array('is_accepted' => 1))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product has been accepted!'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run updateAll query from accept function as shown below:

```
public function accept($id = null){

  if(!empty($id)){
   $this->Product->updateAll(
    array('Product.is_accepted' => 1),
    array('Product.id' => $id)
   );
  }

}
```

Hope this will help you...

For reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html